# Which assembly language statement executes faster?

Tags: assembly, x86

i'm learning assembly language on x86 and meet a problem, which follow is faster and why?

```
ADD AX, 100 

ADD AX, BX
```

The answer in book is the second, but I think that the second one need to read a register first where the first one can add directly. So can anyone please tell me the answer?

Comment: In the first one, the values come out of the wiring from the adder to the instruction decoder (for the immediate value), and in the second one the values come out of the wiring to the registers. Both should take the same amount of cycles. But you can look up cycle counts for operations in the architecture documentation. The second form may be more constraining on instruction reordering, which is hard to quantify out of context.

Comment: What does "reading a register" mean? Where is it getting read to?

Comment: Which book? Does it give any reasoning along with the answer?

Comment: That depends on so many things that this question really can't be answered as-is.

Comment: Makes no difference, a single micro-op and 0.33 cycles throughput for both.  Use [Agner Fog's instruction tables](http://www.agner.org/optimize/instruction_tables.pdf) to look up these details by yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In modern processors there is no difference in performance.  If you change the immediate from 100 to 128 (or larger) then there might be a significant difference.  I know that sounds strange.

There are several manufacturers of x86 processors (Intel, AMD, Via), and each has many generations of processor designs (micro-architectures).  Your question cannot be answered in general because the answer depends on the micro-architecture.  For Intel, a good resource for this sort of question is the

[Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures Optimization Reference Manual](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/architecture-and-technology/64-ia-32-architectures-optimization-manual.html)

Modern high performance CPUs are complex machines.  For most code you shouldn't have to worry about this level of detail, you write in a high level language, use an optimizing compiler, and be happy.  When the performance of your code is vital you might have to be concerned with these details.  If that's the case, then you need to understand the specific micro-architecture you are targeting, which mode the processor is in, and perhaps the actual value of the immediate (surprise!).  Relevant to your question is whether the processor is in

- Real Mode (16-bit)
- 32-bit mode, or [x86-64 long mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_mode)

The instruction in your question `ADD AX,100` is adding a 16-bit immediate (which can be encoded as a signed 8 bit immediate) to a 16-bit register.  That can be done with a different opcode than if you use a signed immediate that doesn't fit in 8 bits.  I used the following website to assemble these instructions:

https://defuse.ca/online-x86-assembler.htm#disassembly

Notice that encoding an `ADD` of an 8-bit signed immediate to `AX` can be done using a different opcode than encoding and `ADD` with a 16-bit signed immediate.

#### 16-bit (Real Mode, Virtual 8086 Mode)

```
0:  83 c0 64             add    ax,100
3:  05 80 00             add    ax,128
```

You might be wondering, so what? it is the same number of bytes... but there's more to it than that.  In 32-bit mode, some instruction encodings that in Real Mode were interpreted as a a 16-bit `ADD` are now interpreted as a 32-bit `ADD`.  In order to encode a 16-bit add in 32-bit mode x86 requires an `operand size override prefix byte`, 0x66.  The encoding of 8-bit `ADD` remains the same:

#### 32-bit or x86-64 (long mode)

```
0:  66 83 c0 64             add    ax,100
4:  66 05 80 00             add    ax,128
8:     83 c0 64             add    eax,100
b:     05 80 00 00 00       add    eax,128
```

Here's the important thing, notice that the 0x05 opcode is followed by either two bytes (when the 0x66 prefix is present) or four bytes (the default, when 0x66 is not present).  This wreaks havoc with the instruction predecoder which is trying to decode many instructions at once and since x86 instructions can be anywhere from 1 to 15 bytes it makes assumptions about default sizes based on opcodes.  The 0x66 prefix on instructions that have 16-bit immediate changes the overall length of the instruction... this is known as a `length changing prefixes (LCP)` and can introduce a **three to six cycle stall** in the decoder, depending on micro-architecture, which can be significant.

Search for the following rules in Intel's optimization manual for more information

> **Assembly/Compiler Coding Rule 21**. (MH impact, MH generality) Favor
>   generating code using imm8 or imm32 values instead of imm16 values.

and

> **Assembly/Compiler Coding Rule 27**. (M impact, MH generality) Avoid
>   using prefixes to change the size of immediate and displacement.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the context (the rest of the program).

The second instruction introduces a data dependency, if you just had to load BX from main memory, you may have to stall for a long time. On the other hand, the first instruction increases the data footprint, and therefore needs more space in the instruction cache to encode the immediate value, which may be critical if it's just enough to cause a few extra misses in some performance-critical loop.

On top of that, there are CPUs today that can perform register copies without executing anything (just using register renaming), so it also depends on the exact micro-architecture you use.

My advice is - find another book, one that does not presume to tell you what will always happen. Also, using AX and BX implies it's rather old...

Answer (score 1):

The answer will depend on the actual implementation of the CPU, which depends on when it was designed.  Older CPUs in will have different timings than newer ones.

With modern CPUs, in general these will be the same speed, because the CPU designers have thrown a huge amount of resources at making basic instructions fast in common cases.

Even so, one can construct circumstances in which the ADD AX,BX will be faster (last instruction fully within the cache line, with the next cache line not yet arrived from memory even with prefetch) and some in which the ADD AX, 100 will be faster (BX is fed by some earlier instruction which takes a long time to complete).

For this particular pair of instructions, I wouldn't spend much time worrying about it.  Best you write your code using what you think are reasonable choices (float-add is almost always slower than integer-add because it is much more complex). [Once you have written a fair amount of assembly code this is pretty easy]. After you have running code, measure performance and optimize where necessary.  Usually the place that needs optimization is a surprise.

Answer (score 0):

In older 80X86 CPUs, immediate values to operands needed to be read from memory, while register operands were encoded in the instruction itself, which already was 'read'. So

```
add ax, bx
```

was a single instruction; after reading it, everything needed was "inside" the CPU and could be processed immediately.

The instruction

```
add ax, 100
```

was parsed as `add ax, ?` and so the CPU needed to read the next word from memory before it could continue.

This is no longer true for new CPUs, but the book the OP  refers to (its title and publication date are not mentioned) may very well be old enough.

Comment: The 100 is an immediate (0x64), it's encoded as just one extra byte **in the instruction**. Both instructions have a ModR/M and one byte opcode. The only difference here is a 25-30% longer instruction, that's negligible. The immediate is **not** read from somewhere else in memory, it's in the instruction just like the register operand.

Comment: @tux3: ah you're right. I may have been thinking of `mov ax,[100]`. Will delete this answer.

Comment: @harold: since OP's source seems old, that is a perfectly valid interpretation. Maybe I should edit it in then?

Comment: I think the point is the answer is technology dependent, and that depends on state of the technology at some specific point in time. So the answer is, "it depends on the technology of the CPU you are using".  There's not much else to say unless you want to talk about architectural *possibilities* and that's rather a big topic.

Answer (score 0):

Go back far enough to 8086/8088, and lea ax,100[ax] was faster than add ax,100 . I'm not sure about 80286.